# In SOClass, how to prevent an Operation from completing from the client side?

Tags: java

Sometimes in your client code, you want to cancel the current operation or prevent it from completing. How can you do that?

Comment: What is SOClass? And do you think it makes sense to add just a single tag that is also new? Often such questions end up untagged, because the new single tag was not used by any other question for a while and the tag got deleted again.

Comment: [SOClass](https://strategyobject.com/products/about-soclass/) is a Java based framework that is used by the [ASYCUDA](https://asycuda.org/en/) software which is used by many Customs agencies around the world. As for the tag getting deleted due to lack of activity, this is very possible. I am not sure what to do about that though.

Comment: @jps I just realized I did not answer your second question. The two other tags I considered were `java` and `asycuda`. However, all the concepts in the question are defined at the SOClass framework level, even though they are implemented in java and used by ASYCUDA. In other words, `java` would be too general, and `asycuda` would be too specific. I also made sure to put "In SOClass,..." at the beginning of the question so that people know right away if the question concerns them or not. Do you think I should change that to "In the SOClass framework,..." just to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add a client rule to the FINAL_ACTION_REQUESTED event that consumes it. This will stop the operation from completing:

```java
document.addRule(new Rule() {
            @Override
            protected void apply(KernelEvent e) {
                e.consume();
            }
        }, KernelEventConstants.FINAL_ACTION_REQUESTED);
```

Since this could be a common scenario for you, you might also want to define a utility class to handle this situation. This also helps in preventing adding that rule multiple times across your code, which is not neat and also might have a performance penalty:

```java
public final class OperationUtility {

    private static volatile Rule preventOperationFromCompletingRule = null;


    public static void preventOperationFromCompleting(KDocument doc) {
        if (preventOperationFromCompletingRule == null) {
            synchronized (OperationUtility.class) {
                if (preventOperationFromCompletingRule == null) {
                    preventOperationFromCompletingRule = new Rule() {
                        @Override
                        protected void apply(KernelEvent e) {
                            e.consume();
                        }
                    };

                    doc.addRule(preventOperationFromCompletingRule, KernelEventConstants.FINAL_ACTION_REQUESTED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code uses the Singleton Pattern with Lazy Initialization as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization

And in your code you use the utility as follows:

```java
OperationUtility.preventOperationFromCompleting(doc);
```